# NOP code in the disassembly output for pointer

Tags: pointers, disassembly, keil

I wonder to know why there is the NOP for initializing a pointer as depicted below ??

I have even defined a global variable but faced the same result

Good to mention that I use the default ARM compiler version 5 and set the optimization to level 0.

[image]

Comment: Educated guess: For some processors aligning branch targets by inserting noop instructions is an optimization.  See e.g. http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731168556.htm. That's probably what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks Gene for your comment but it wouldn't be an issue here. nothing happened when I reference an address to a pointer.

Comment: You're not understanding. The pointer value #BEEF is assigned by the STR instruction. The next thing in the source is `while(1){}`.  This compiles to the single branch that jumps to itself.  I'm saying the compiler inserted a NOOP so that the branch target falls at 280 rather than 27C.  280 is on a 16-byte boundary, which is a very common alignment.  27C is on a 4-byte boundary, which is not.

Comment: Thanks gene if I have understood correctly you explain the NOP and the reason that we have it in the disassembly code so why I don't have the address of bitband in the pointer(bitbandAddress), if you see  the watch 1 window

Comment: The compiler has optimized away the pointer assignment because the value is never used.  If you do something like call another function with the pointer as argument, you'll see the address-taking in the compiled code.

Comment: Thanks Gene, this was my problem, I thought if I set the optimize level in level 0 the compiler doesn't eliminate the code. I would be appreciate if you write the solution in the answer section .